# Cannot rip audio CD where each track appears as a data track

Tags: audio, backup, compact-disc, flac, copy-protection

Over the past few weeks I've converted my entire (store-bought) CD collection to .flac files, both for backup purposes as well as easier playback. Several of the CDs featured copy protection, but I was still able to convert them by various methods (different cdrom/dvdrom, different software, different OS, etc...).

Alas, there is one double-CD which I cannot convert, and I'm at a loss as to what I should try next to create a .flac version of it. As soon as I enter the CD into a drive, the drive starts spinning up, stopping, clicking, and repeating the process. After a while, tools such as Exact Audio Copy or CDex show a list of 11 data tracks in one session (for both discs), which cannot be ripped.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how I can create a backup of this CD?

There are some things I'd like to clarify upfront:

- yes, I own the CD (I've bought thousands of them in the past), and I can prove it
- in my country it is legal to create as well as own a backup copy of store-bought media
- I cannot buy the CD online - iTunes, Spotify, you name it: they don't know this CD (apparently half of my collection is "unknown" to both)
- I cannot contact the record company or record label, both are out of business
- the CD plays perfectly on ANY audio player, but cannot be played on a PC - I've tried my 8 Windows machines, a few Linux machines and a Mac.
- some CDs I had, had an extra track containing data or an executable to defeat copying/ripping - this is not the same type of protection
- other CDs had a little black ring near the edge as protection (basically also a data track), this CD doesn't.

Besides making a backup copy of my CDs, I'd also like to know exactly HOW they did this. I have never come across an audio copy protection scheme that wasn't easily circumvented, so this one really puzzles me, and as a software developer, I'd like to know the details ;)

Thanks in advance!

Marlon

Comment: This is going to sound... generic and cliche, but have you tried Googling for rips of this particular album? It might not be the first time someone has tried to make a backup of this particular CD, and there could useful information out there.

Comment: @Michael Frank - yes, I've tried Googling for other methods to rip CDs, other software/tools/etc, and as a last resort I've tried various fora and filesharing networks to find this particular CD. I own all other CDs in this collection, and i can find all other CDs in the collection, but this one is nowhere to be found. This leads me to believe that I'm not the only one who's having troubles creating a backup...

Answer (score 0):

You could probably try to rip the CD using a software like [ImgBurn](https://www.imgburn.com/), which should generate you a .bin/.cue pair of files.

Once you have this files, you can split the bin using [binmerge](https://github.com/putnam/binmerge) and the `--split` argument, you can then import this bins to [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) using `File > Import > Raw Data...` and picking one bin file.

In the window that appears after selecting a file you need to input this specific parameters for an audio CD:

- Encoding: Signed 16-bit PCM
- Byte order: Little-endian
- Channels: 2 Channels (Stereo)
- Start offset: 0 (you may possibly need to adjust this)
- Amount to import: 100%
- Sample rate: 44100 Hz

If this decodes your file correctly, then you can export it using `File > Export > Export Audio` and save it as a FLAC.

Do this for every bin file and you get your rip. Of course you can skip the splitting of the bin file, but then you have to split the resulting flac.